# A 404 error installing Pimcore CMS

Tags: installation, pimcore

When I try to install Pimcore on my localhost, it shows this error:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
>
> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
>
> Requested URL  http://localhost/install/

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you have set AllowOverride All in your  directive for your vhost.

Please see also: https://www.pimcore.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=16854184

There's a step by step guide wich covers also your problem.